.NET - What happens to tasks that don't complete before the method finishes?
Apologies if this isn't asked well--this basically my first time posting, but I'm a long time lurker.
I'm troubleshooting some .NET6 code that is looping through a list of a few thousand items, and the code is essentially this:
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    foreach (var thing in things)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () => DoSomeStuffThatTakesAWhile(thing))
    }
}

The DoSomeStuffThatTakesAWhile() has a log at the very top, so I can see when each task gets into there. What I'm seeing is those logs for about 20% of the items in the list, and then nothing else. No errors, exceptions, or any other indications of a problem. It seems to abruptly just stop part way down the list.
I'm not able to make code changes at the moment and think I could answer this question myself with a little bit of logging. But unfortunately that's not an option at the moment.
I expected to see the log from DoSomeStuffThatTakesAWhile() for each of the items in the list.
My theory is that any tasks that were not scheduled onto a thread by the time MyMethod() completes are just getting dropped and never run. Is that how this works? I'm thinking that sticking those tasks into a list and doing a WaitAll() at the end of MyMethod might resolve this.
Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Is that how this works? - no. Does the program also exit when MyMethod() completes?

No, the program doesn't end when MyMethod() completes. It's part of a service that is always up and runs this method periodically.

And thank you for the reference link!

What is the type of the application? ASP.NET maybe?

BTW, the reason for "does the program exit" is that Task.Run dispatches work to the thread pool. Threads in the thread pool are background threads (i.e., their IsBackground property is true). When all of the foreground threads in a process end, any remaining background threads are terminated.

If you do what you mentioned and add the tasks to a list, at the end of the method you can do await Task.WhenAll(yourTaskList);.

Currently, as your program is a service that is always running, the background threads will continue after the method ends.

Thank you all for the information! @TheodorZoulias, it's a .NET 8 application. I misstated above that it was .NET 6. It sounds like I'm barking up the wrong tree with my original idea

I asked about the type of the application: WinForms, Console App, Windows service, ASP.NET etc. .NET 8 is the version of the .NET platform, which is good to know but not what I asked.

The kestrel pipeline creates a service scope per request, and disposes it when the request is complete. You are probably accessing a disposed service, but you aren't observing any exceptions.

@TheodorZoulias Sorry, yes it's an ASP.NET web service project.
